# Control Loop Statement from Exception Block Oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to know if there is any way in oracle to redirect the control from exception block to the current begin/end block.

Following is the code snippet.  **i** variable loops through the table data sets, I want to update table **i**; if there is any exception go to the **exec1** exception block,do the stuff and then try updating table **i** again.

If control goes to the **exec2** exception then continue to the next iteration.

I want help as after performing steps in **exec1** exception, how can I try updating table(i) again; so that if it fails again it is handled in **exec1** exception block.

```
FOR i in c_tables
  LOOP
  BEGIN
   ---label---
   Update (i);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('ROWS UPDATED IS: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
 EXCEPTION
  WHEN  exec1 THEN
    BEGIN
     do_stuff();
     goto label;
   EXCEPTION WHEN exec2 THEN 
  do_stuff();
   continue;
   END;    
 END;
 END LOOP;
```

Comment: the goto label statement in exec1 block is throwing error, so want to know the solution.

Comment: Instead of `goto label`, do `update (i)`. If it is a lot of code, create a procedure instead. If it is a simple UPDATE statement, copy/paste it into the first exception block.

Comment: @sqlpractice: please edit your question and include information about the error which is being thrown. Thanks.

Comment: @Littlefoot I want to execute update(i) upto to the point where it either goes to exception2 block or is successful..if I include it in exc1 block and if it fails again with the same exception(exec1) it will throw an error and will be not caught in exec1 block..

Comment: Aha. I thought that do_stuff fixes reason for the exec1 error. You said that "goto is throwing error" - which one?

Comment: @Littlefoot  do_stuff() fixes the error, but after fixing I have to update(i) again and then there is a possibility that it gets the same exception again..
goto label in exec1 is giving error.
PLS-00375: illegal GOTO statement; this GOTO cannot branch to label 'LABEL'

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate what you have, in Scott's schema.

It seems that you'd be good if you moved the label in front of the BEGIN, not after it. Have a look:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_deptno_dflt   NUMBER := 50;
  3  BEGIN
  4     FOR i IN (SELECT distinct deptno FROM emp)
  5     LOOP
  6        <<this_is_label>>           -- put label here ...
  7        BEGIN
  8        -- <<this_is_label>>        -- ... not here
  9           UPDATE emp
 10              SET deptno = l_deptno_dflt
 11            WHERE deptno = i.deptno;
 12
 13           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('rows updated is ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
 14        EXCEPTION
 15           WHEN OTHERS
 16           THEN
 17              DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('this is exec1');
 18
 19              BEGIN
 20                 l_deptno_dflt := 40;
 21                 goto this_is_label;
 22              END;
 23        END;
 24     END LOOP;
 25  END;
 26  /
this is exec1
rows updated is 6
rows updated is 5
rows updated is 3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

If it is where you initially put it, it raises the mentioned PLS-00375 error.